# What's wrong with my disproof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, diophantine-equations

> Determine all triples $(x,y,z)$ of positive integers such that $$(x+y)^2 + 3x + y + 1 = z^2$$

Assume $x\geq y$ then

$$(x+x)^2 + 3x + x + 1  = 4x^2 + 4x + 1\geq z^2$$

Taking this as a quadratic in $x$ we have $\Delta = 4^2 - 4(4)(1-z^2) \leq 0 \implies 16z^2 \leq 0 \implies z = 0$, but $z\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

Contradiction.

However the problem does actually have solutions of the form $k,k,2k+1$

Comment: You didn't assume $x\geq y$, you directly assumed $x = y$.

Comment: Try to set $y = k x$ instead.

Comment: @FourierTransform $(x+x)^2 + 3x + x + 1 \geq (x+y)^2 + 3x + y +1$ , no?

Comment: $\Delta=4^2-4(4)(1-z^2)=+16z^2\geq 0.$ Consider that $4x^2+4x+1\geq $ $z^2\iff (2x+1)^2\geq $ $ z^2\iff 2x+1\geq z.$ Also the equation is not symmetric in $ x,y $ so we cannot assume $x\geq y.$

Comment: You have only showed that if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution then $16z^2 > 0$. I don't see any contradiction here.

Comment: For the case $x=y$ the quadratic in $x$ is

Comment: For the case $x=y$ the quadratic in $x$ is $$4x^2+4x+1-z^2=0$$ which gives, for positive $x$, $x=0.5(-1+z)$ This equates to the solution you stated.